# Exception: The parameters (String,number,String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to copy the first 7 columns from spreadsheet1(369) and spreadsheet2(370) and paste them in spreadsheet3 with the number 369 and 370 next to the data, but im keep getting this error which I don't know why.

```
function MoveCode(){
  wn1=369;
  wn2=370;
  wn3=371;
  wn4=372;
  const ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sshActive = ssActive.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  const ss369 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A3tJiIEkDP_5R6mEY25IeAsO2XV_oveJwnUovxRd-1U");//or url whatever
  const dsh369 = ss369.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const lastRow369 = dsh369.getLastRow();//getting the last row
  //Adding the week number to the first row
  sshActive.getRange("A2").setValue("Week Number")
  var number369 = (dsh369.getLastRow()-2).toString();
  number369 = number369.replace(".0","");
  sshActive.getRange(3,1,number369).setValue(wn1);
  Logger.log(number369);
  
  const vs369 = dsh369.getRange(2, 1, lastRow369 - 1, 7).getValues();//we are getting the data and storing it in vs
  sshActive.getRange(2, 2, vs369.length, vs369[0].length).setValues(vs369);//we are pasting the code to the new sheet from dsh
  
  
  const ssActive370 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sshActive370 = ssActive370.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  const ss370 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HL1OH0ghlQCS7fMZsiVKI9ELab8HRVXW6QtruPiKedY");
  const dsh370 = ss370.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const lastRow370 = dsh370.getLastRow();//getting the last row

  var number370 = (dsh370.getLastRow()-2).toString();
  number370 = number370.replace(".0","");
Logger.log(number369);
  Logger.log(number370);
  ssActive370.getRange(number369+3,1,number370).setValue(wn2);
  Logger.log(number370);

  const vs370 = dsh370.getRange(2, 1, lastRow370 - 1, 7).getValues();//we are getting the data and storing it in vs
  ssActive370.getRange(number369+3, 2, vs370.length, vs370[0].length).setValues(vs370);//we are pasting the code to the new sheet from dsh
  
}
```

I,m not relly sure why its giving me that error, because im using (number,number,number) *I believe*.

The error is on line 34

If you need more info please let me know

Comment: Could you share an example spreadsheet to check the error? Remember to try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue so the community can have a clear view of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ssActive370.getRange(parseInt(number369+3),1,parseInt(number370)).setValue(wn2);
```

Try doing the copy this way:

```
function MoveCode() {
  const ss369 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A3tJiIEkDP_5R6mEY25IeAsO2XV_oveJwnUovxRd-1U");
  const ss370 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1HL1OH0ghlQCS7fMZsiVKI9ELab8HRVXW6QtruPiKedY");
  const ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  const ssh = ssActive.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dsh369 = ss369.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
  const dsh370 = ss370.getSheetByName('Sourcing');
 
  const vs369 = dsh369.getRange(2, 1, dsh369.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
  const vs370 = dsh370.getRange(2, 1, dsh370.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();

  ssh.getRange(2, 2, vs369.length, vs369[0].length).setValues(vs369);
  //SpreadsheetApp.flush();//you might want this 
  ssh.getRange(ssh.getLastRow() + 1, 2, vs370.length, vs370[0].length).setValues(vs370);//you may have to reposition the starting row here
}
```

I left a couple of things out like putting the "Week Number" header in column A and something you were doing with the wns at the top which seemed unnecessary.  But the basic copying should be relative close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue and solution:

I thought that in your script, such the error occurs at `ssActive370.getRange(number369+3,1,number370).setValue(wn2);` and `ssActive370.getRange(number369+3, 2, vs370.length, vs370[0].length).setValues(vs370);`. Because `ssActive370` is the object of Class Spreadsheet from `const ssActive370 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`. The method of "getRange" in Class Spreadsheet is only `getRange(a1Notation)`. I thought that this is the reason of your issue of `Exception: The parameters (String,number,String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange`. In order to use `getRange(row, column, numRows)` and `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`, it is required to use the method of Class Sheet.

When you want to remove this issue, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
const ssActive370 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const sshActive370 = ssActive370.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

##### To:

```
const ssActive370 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

#### References:

- [getRange(a1Notation) of Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)